# An example of a Grothendieck topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

A Grothendieck topology on a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite limits consists of, for each object $U$ in $\mathcal{C}$ a collection $\text{Cov}(U)$ of sets $\{ U_i \to U \}$ such that

- Isomorphisms are covers, e.g if $V \to U$ is an isomorphism then $\{ V \to U \} \in \text{Cov}(U)$
- Transitivity: If $\{V_i \to U \}$ and $\{V_{ij} \to V_i \}$ are coverings then $\{V_{ij} \to U \}$ is also a covering
- If $\{U_i \to U \} \in \text{Cov}(U)$ and $V \to U$ a morphism then $\{V \times_U U_i \to V \} \in \text{Cov(V)}$

The claim is that the following is a covering:

$\mathcal{C} = \text{Rings}^{\text{op}}$, and coverings are the opposite of collections $\{R \to R_i \}$ where

- Each $R \to R_i$ is flat
- If $M$ is an $R$-module such that $M \otimes_R R_i=0$ for all $i$ then $M=0$

(I have interpreted $R \to R_i$ as flat as meaning $R_i$ is flat as an $R$-module)

I (think) I have verified the first two conditions (isomorphism and transitivity). For example the second part of transitivity will follow since:
$$
\begin{align}
0 &\simeq M\otimes_{U} V_{ij}\\
 &\simeq M \otimes_{U}\left(U_i \otimes_{U_i}V_{ij}\right) \\
 &\simeq \left(M \otimes_{U} U_i \right) \otimes_{U_i} V_{ij} 
\end{align}$$
which gives that $M \otimes_U U_i=0$ which in turn gives $M=0$

I'm not sure how to interpret the fiber product in item 3. For example I want to show that $M \otimes_V (V \times_U U_i)=0$ gives $M=0$, but I have no idea what the fiber product is in this category, and how it interacts with the tensor product.

Comment: Feel free to re-tag, I'm really not sure what to tag it as

Comment: The fibre product in the _opposite_ category of commutative rings is the tensor product. This question is about topos theory, and strictly speaking what you have defined is called a pretopology. The topology you are asking about is also known as the fpqc topology.

Comment: @Zhen - thanks. This pretty much answers my question, so feel free to post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The fibre product in $\textbf{CRing}^\textrm{op}$, also known as the category of affine schemes $\textbf{Aff}$, corresponds to the tensor product of rings.
2. Strictly speaking what you have defined is called a Grothendieck pretopology.
3. If one has a flat ring homomorphism $R \to R'$ such that $M \otimes_R R' = 0$ if and only if $M = 0$, then we say $R'$ is *faithfully flat* over $R$. The (pre)topology you are describing is called the fpqc topology, where fpqc stands for *fidèlement plat et quasicompact* (faithfully flat and quasicompact).